# How to write simplified and generic validation logics and rules in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I know there are tons of information out there over internet to validate form in JavaScript and JQuery. But I’m interested to write my own. Basically I want to learn this thing.

So here is my validation script I have written and its working fine.

```
function validate() {

        var firstName = jQuery("#firstName").val();
        var lastName = jQuery("#lastName").val();
        var dateOfBirthy = jQuery().val("dateOfBirth");

        if (firstName.length == 0) {
            addRemoveValidationCSSclass("#firstName", false);
        } else {
            addRemoveValidationCSSclass("#firstName", true);
        }

        if (lastName.length == 0) {
            addRemoveValidationCSSclass("#lastName", false);
        } else {
            addRemoveValidationCSSclass("#lastName", true);
        }
    }

    function addRemoveValidationCSSclass(inputField, isValid) {
        var div = jQuery(inputField).parents("div.control-group");
        if (isValid == false) {
            div.removeClass("success");
            div.addClass("error");
        } else if (isValid == true) {
            div.removeClass("error");
            div.addClass("success");
        } else {
        }
    }
```

I want to achieve few things--

1. add validation message
2. More generic way to handle for every form.
3. And I want to add validation rule, like length, email validation,
   date validation etc.

Now how can I achieve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to this, except that I wrote my rules in `PHP` since you need a server-side backup. When the PHP generates the form, it also generates some simple client-side validation that looks like this:

```
<!-- html field -->
<label for="first">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
  <span id="first_message"></span>
</label>
```

Then the script is like this:

```
<script>
  var formValid = true;
  var fieldValid = true;

  // Check first name
  fieldValid = doRequiredCheck("first");
  if (!fieldValid) {formValid = false};
  fieldValid = doCheckLength("first", 25);
  if (!fieldValid) {formValid = false};

  function doRequiredCheck(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var box = document.getElementById(id + "_message";
    if (el.value === "") {
      box.innerHTML = "**REQUIRED**";
    }
  }

  function doCheckLength(id,len) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var box = document.getElementById(id + "_message";
    if (el.value.length > len) {
      box.innerHTML = "Too long";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). It does everything you want straight out of the box.

Comment: There is a problem using JQuery validate.Here i need to submit form to validate. but I don't want to submit form. I just want make sure is the form fields are valid pressing a simple button or anything. link, like I said, i want in way of learning things. thanks btw.

Comment: You can check the form is valid without submitting in in jQuery validate: `if ($("form").valid()) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple function:

```
function validations(day, hour, tap1, tap2, employed){
if( day== "" | hour== "" | tap1== "" | tap2== "" | employed== "" ){
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```